# Ignore Pylance missing imports

Tags: visual-studio-code, import, pylance

I'm trying to modify my settings.json file for VSCode to ignore missing imports for my own scripts. As i've learnt I have to set "python.analysis.useImportHeuristic" to true. Code says it is an unknown configuration setting but as long as I've searched I haven't seen any info about it. What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 13):

insert this:

```
# type: ignore
```

paste it at the top of the file to ignore the file

paste it at the end of a line to ignore the line

Reference: https://www.reddit.com/r/VisualStudioCode/comments/i3mpct/comment/g5bkx9u/

Comment: this also ignores the line for mypy which actually does a better job than pylance and will correctly complain about the type ignore because it is useless. is there a pylance specific ignore?

Answer (score 8):

Add this to your settings.json:

```
"python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
    "reportMissingImports": "none"
}
```